# Delphi Indy ICMP Ping vs Windows Ping

Tags: delphi, ping, indy

Is there a fundamental difference between Indy's ICMP ping and the ping I can perform on the windows command line?

I am experiencing the following phenomenon while building a kind of presence sensor regulary pinging the phones of the persons in my household with the Indy ICMP component. All phones are android and all have W-Lan connected also in standby:

All phones except for mine are perfectly discovered. Mine is sometimes discovered, most of the time not, independent of the sleep state. I have the same brand and model and Android version (all unrooted) like my daughter, discovering hers works perfectly fine. My phone is often not discovered when not in stand by.

When my phone was not discovered for some time I just tried pinging it from the Windows command line from the same host and it responds within a few hundred milliseconds.

Before I use windows ping for that purpose, what involves capturing output and so on, I would like to find out the cause of this phenomenon. Is someone aware of a fundamental difference?

Comment: Can you show us your code? Error handling and timeouts are important things.

Comment: I will when I return to my office. Of course I use the same timeout and expect no error.

Comment: Ultimately, an ICMP ping is an ICMP ping regardless of implementation. However, Indy and `ping.exe` do implement ICMP pinging using very different APIs. If one is working and the other is not, use a packet sniffer to look at the network traffic to see what's different in the ICMP packets.